# Julia Can't Test User Packages

Tags: julia

I have a Julia package I developed locally, let's call it `mypack`, and I can't automatically test it with Julia in `pkg` mode. Running `pkg>test mypack` gives me the following error:

```
(v1.3) pkg> test mypack
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/environments/v1.3/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
   Testing mypack
 Resolving package versions...
[ Info: No changes
    Status `/tmp/jl_m6URie/Manifest.toml`
  [4e168b6d] mypack v0.1.0 [`~/Documents/mypack`]
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Test not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Test")` to install the Test package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:887
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:424
 [6] top-level scope at none:6
in expression starting at /home/myname/Documents/mypack/test/runtests.jl:1
ERROR: Package mypack errored during testing
```

My `mypack` project has the expected structure where there's a root directory with a `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` generated using `]generate mypack`. `/test/runtests.jl` is just the line

```
using Test
```

This works on two machines that I've tested it on, one of which was using Julia 1.1 and one which was using Julia 1.2. The errors are happening on a new install of Julia 1.3.

I am able to test other packages (such as `Statistics` just fine, which I did to make sure `Test` was working). I have a more complicated project which brought this to my attention, but this `mypack` MWE is also broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `Pkg.test`, Pkg creates a test environment. This environment consists of direct dependencies and test dependencies. Any dependency which is imported by `test/runtests.jl` needs to be in this test environment.

Because your `test/runtests.jl` imports the `Test` standard library, you need to add it as a test dependency. You can add test dependencies using this method: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/#Test-specific-dependencies-in-Julia-1.0-and-1.1-1.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a warning, or error, or anything to indicate this change without digging through changelogs?